# Convergence and Divergence of sequence with $x_{1} =c$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Prove that the sequence $\ x_n$ where $\ x_{n+1} = {6(1+x_n) \over 7+x_n}, x_1=c>0$ is monotone increasing or decreasing according as $\ c<2$ or $\ c>2$ and that in either case, the sequence converges to 2. Discuss the case $\ c=2$.

Attempt ::

Using Cauchy's General Principle of Convergence,

$\ |x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon$

|$\ x_n^2+x_n -6 \over7+x_n $| $\ < \epsilon$

How do I apply the fact that $\ x_1 =c$ ?

Comment: Have you tried to apply induction?

Comment: Induction will help to prove if it is monotone increasing or decreasing. But it wont be able to prove if it converges to 2.

Comment: I was giving a hint on the monotonicity of the sequence. To prove that it converges to 2 you have to prove, first of all, that it converges to something, then apply limit, change all the $a_n$ for $L$ and solve the equation for $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you denote
$f(x)=\frac{6(1+x)}{7+x}$, you can prove that $f$ is continuous and positive on $[0,\infty)$. Moreover the only fix point of $f$ on this interval is $c=2$. Hence the sequence $(x_n)$ is positive.

Now let's study the values of the sequence compared to the number $2$

$$\begin{aligned}
x_{n+1}- 2 &=\frac{6(1+x_n)}{7+x_n}-2\\
&=4\frac{x_n-2}{7+x_n}
\end{aligned}$$ Hence you can prove by induction that the sequence is either always greater than $2$ or always smaller than $2$.

Now, you have

$$\begin{aligned}
x_{n+1}- x_n &=\frac{6(1+x_n)}{7+x_n}-x_n\\
&=-\frac{x_n^2+x_n -6}{7+x_n}\\
&=-\frac{(x_n-2)(x_n+3)}{7+x_n}
\end{aligned}$$ proving that the sequence is decreasing if the initial value is greater than $ 2$ and increasing if the initial value is smaller than $2$.

Hence in both cases the sequence converge. As $f$ is continuous, the limit is a fix point. As the only positive fix point is $2$, we have proven that the sequence converges to $2$ is all cases.

Comment: What do you mean by fixed point is c=2?